# Undo modifying of files while switching branches in Git

Tags: git, github, terminal

So I had made changes to my local branch A. I forgot to stash those changes before switching to branch B, and now branch B has all those changes from branch A.

These are quite a few changes and I would really rather not manually tease through them.

How can I simply undo the command:

git checkout branch_b

it is my last command I made with git if that helps make the problem easier to solve

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch B doesn't "have all those changes", unless you actually committed all those files.  All that's happened so far is that you've *switched* to branch B, and those changes are still outstanding in your work directory.  You have a few options:

- You can switch back to branch A and commit the changes.

  ```
  git checkout branch_a
  git commit -m "some stuff that should be on branch_a"
  ```

  And then switch back to branch B.
- You can can switch to branch A and "stash" the changes:

  ```
  git checkout branch_a
  git stash
  ```

  Later on, if you want to continue working on those changes:

  ```
  git checkout branch_a
  git stash pop
  ```
- You can create a new branch based on branch A as a temporary place to storing those changes:

  ```
  git checkout -b work_on_branch_a branch_a
  git add -u
  git commit -m "work in progress for branch a"
  ```

  Later on, you could merge those changes back into branch a, or just forget about them if you decide they are no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, cleared things up for me